# After creating a mailing using Mosaico, can one save that as a new Mosaico template?

Tags: civimail, mosaico

Quick answer seems to be no.

Create a new mailing, pick one of the Mosaico templates.  Add blocks, change text, etc., save it.  Now after all that work I thought I'd like to save this as a new Mosaico template.

Clicked on the little save icon next to the Template pull down on the very first screen of new mailing.  Entered a name, saved it.  It saved it as a regular template, which is nice for the folks wanting a way to save a Mosaico template to use for regular email.

I'll be happy to enter a new issue for this if it's a bug or feature enhancement.

Using civicrm 5.9.1, Mosaico 2.0-Beta4

Comment: +1 - would be a useful feature